# Reported Speech- Backshift of tenses

Tags: reported-speech

Why to back shift the tenses in Reported speech when the incident or news is still true?

In New paper reporter back shifts the tense while reporting the news. But some time the speakers reported speech is still true or still happening while reading.

e.g.

"He added that demonetization had hurt the poor and the economy and the policy was a disaster."

Refer this link.

http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/PM-Modi-is-interested-in-doing-only-TRP-politics-Rahul-Gandhi/articleshow/55743392.cms

If I say

"He added that demonetization has hurt the poor and the economy and the policy is a disaster."
It will mean the same thing.

Please help me to understand when to backshift tense and when not?

Answer (score 2):

> If the statement is still true, backshifting tense in reported speech is **optional**

So that means

> "He added that demonetization *had hurt* the poor and the economy and the policy *was* a disaster."

And

> "He added that demonetization *has hurt* the poor and the economy and the policy *is* a disaster."

Are both correct.

Answer (score 1):

If the speaker said

> "Demonetization has hurt the poor and the economy and the policy is a disaster"

Then you would report it as

> He added that demonetization had hurt the poor and the economy and the policy was a disaster.

If the speaker said

> "Demonetization has hurt the poor and the economy"

Then you would report it as

> He added that demonetization had hurt the poor and the economy.

If you want to add your own opinion about the policy, you can say:

> He added that demonetization had hurt the poor and the economy and the policy is a disaster.

If you backshift **is** to **was**, it is clear that you are quoting what the speaker said. If you do not, this last clause could be interpreted as a statement of your own opinion, rather than a quote